# I would like I search for Facebook public posts with Keyword. how?

Tags: facebook, public, posts

Please help me 
I would like I search for public posts with Keyword " Crafts " in facebook
(i.e., from users , photos , videos ). Any ideas ?? Do you know any site ? , program ?for public posts with Keyword in facebook. facebook graph ?
But unfortunately April 30th 2015 Facebook deprecated the Search API for public posts by keywords, which provided poor results and was unstable. 
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You can´t.

As you found out already:

> Public Post search is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

There is only the Public Feed API, but you cannot apply at the moment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

This is the only possibility to search for something, and it does not include posts: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search